# Deleting a file from a bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm trying to delete an object from a bucket. Reading the docs it all sounds super simple, but I just can't seem to get it working.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-DELETE/) to try and delete this object, which I can see using `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/my-persistent-bucket/objects`:

```
bucketKey => 'my-persistent-bucket'
        objectKey => '--test2.dwg'
        objectId => 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:my-persistent-bucket/--test2.dwg'
        sha1 => '477085439a60779064d91fd1971d53c77c7a163a'
        size => (int) 188600
        location => 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/my-persistent-bucket/objects/--test2.dwg'
```

According to the docs we use this end point:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName
```

Where

`:bucketKey` is url encoded `'my-persistent-bucket'`

`:objectName` is url encoded `'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:my-persistent-bucket/--test2.dwg'`

I've tried using PHP's `urlencode()` and the following base64 encode function:

```
private function _base64url_encode($data) {
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

to encode the `:bucketKey` and `:objectName` but no matter how I try to encode it I always get:

```
404 : Object not found
```

Could anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, after I've made a SO post I find the answer.

For anyone having the same issues you must encode your `:objectName`, which is just the filename, in my example `'--test2.dwg'`, using PHP's `rawurlencode()` function rather than `urlencode()`.

Comment: In Javascript I used encodeURI('--test2.dwg') and it worked